# How to modify and build a rosbuild package from source in ros groovy?

Tags: ros, ros-groovy, find-package, build-from-source, catkin-workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to modify and build the rosfalcon package. I am using ubuntu 12.04 and groovy.

How do I set up a workspace from an existing package in groovy? There seems to be tons of examples about creating a workspace from scratch, but I couldn't locate any about setting up your environment to modify an already existing package. Everything I tried ended up with either ROS not being able to find that package, or the package not building.

So, if I have the sources for a package I want to modify, where do I place them and which commands should I use to tell ROS it exists/build it/install it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65555/how-to-modify-and-build-a-rosbuild-package-from-source-in-ros-groovy?/) by [rsquare](https://answers.ros.org/users/5188/rsquare/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-06-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven't done this for rosfalcon (and can't find any information about it on the wiki), but this has worked for me:

```
cd $catkin_ws/src
git clone http://<blah blah blah>
cd $catkin_ws
catkin_make
roscd <package>
```

Where $catkin_ws is an already existing catkin workspace, whose setup.bash file I've already sourced. I'd guess that you either missed the catkin_make or sourcing the workspace's setup file.

Edit:
Thanks for the link! After downloading the code via:

```
bzr branch http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~cyphylab/cyphy/bonsai
```

It became clear that the problem is this isn't a catkin-ized package. Check [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin/Tutorials/using_rosbuild_with_catkin) out for information about using the old-style rosbuild system with catkin. In short, make sure you have the bonsai directory somewhere in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, after which you should be able to

```
rosmake cyphy_rosfalcon
```

Unfortunately, this gives errors on my system (I'm using OSX), but this should at least solve your build problems.

---

Originally posted by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) with karma: 1780 on 2013-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rsquare](https://answers.ros.org/users/5188/rsquare/) on 2013-06-20**:
Thanks for answering! The rosfalcon package is developped by Queensland UTech, and is located in their bazaar repo, which you can find at tinyurl mvpne3a. I did source the setup file and use catkin_make. It looks like catkin_make doesn't see the package. Anything I can do to fix that?

**Comment by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) on 2013-06-20**:
I'm sorry - I've never used bzr before ... how do I clone that repo, or whatever the equivalent is? ("bzr branch " didn't work for me - I get "not a branch")

**Comment by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) on 2013-06-20**:
(Oh - since you lack the rep to post urls here, feel free to email it to me and I'll post: lindzey[at]gmail)